# Slice polygon into n-pieces

Tags: c#, .net, geometry, polygon, partitioning

I'm working on a polygon slicing algorithm and found a solution to slice a polygon into n-parts. 
The problem is that I just know the lines where the polygon needs to be cutted and these are from a voronoi diagram.

Is there any existing algorithm to cut a polygon into n-parts by having the lines where it needs to be cutted?

Heres a picture to show what I have already:

[image: Polygon (Blue), to be sliced at red lines]

The blue polygon needs to get sliced at the red lines to get (in this case) 7 smaller polygons.

Any idea how to solve this the most efficient way?

Comment: Try using `SqlGeometry` and it's intersect method. You have to reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.Types`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find intersections of your polygon with every cell of Voronoi diagram using, for example, [Clipper library](http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php).

AFAIK, it allows to clip polygon against open voronoi cell (polyline)
[image]

**Edit**  After quick check: library can only clip polyline by closed polygon, returning part of polyline that is inside the polygon. It cannot find part of polygon, cut by polyline (and it is ambiguous operation, of course).
So bounded voronoi diagram would be needed.

Comment: looks pretty good. So it would be better to get a bounded voronoi diagram to do it right? Then I have to look for a library which gives me a bounded voronoi first. thanks for the answer

Comment: Probably not. I have not used this feature, but documentation mention polygon intersection with open path (polyline).

Comment: oh thats awesome! thanks, I'll give it a shot tomorrow =)

Comment: well I just saw it's only working with integer points... I need double though

Comment: Is it possible to scale floats like `IntValue = Round(FloatValue * 1000000.)` ?

Comment: Where do I get the Path class from?

Comment: there is `typedef std::vector< IntPoint > Path;` in clipper.cs